# How to get a related element with Jquery?

Tags: jquery

```
<div class="severalDivs">
    <table>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td class="target">
                    <a href="link"></a>
                </td>
            <tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <div class="fromHere">
        <a href="somescript()"></a>
    </div>
</div>
```

How do I with Jquery get "link" in "target" when clicking the anchor with "somescript()" in "fromHere"?

Hope It's clear what I want to do. =)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You mean like this?

```
$('div.fromHere').find('a').click( function(e) {
    var div = $(this).closest('div.severalDivs');
    var targetLink = div.find('td.target a');
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

This allows you to have several divs like the one you gave as an example, and always find the correct link.

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
$('.fromHere a').click(function(){
   var link = $('.target a').attr('href');
   alert(link);
   return false;
})
```

Answer (score 1):

```
function somescript( ) {
    var href = $("td.target a").attr("href");
}
```